# How do you display particular nodes in a Linked List?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, abstract-class, nodes

I'm am fairly new to C++.

I have this code from an assignment, i don't quite understand all of it, but i have to **make the program give an option at the end for the user to recall any partnumber and model year/engine no. that was entered.**

I have no idea on how to go about doing this task... maybe have some kind of id for each node so i can recall it?

Or is it my only option to rewrite the program using an array or vector data structure?

```
     #include <iostream>

     using namespace std;

     typedef unsigned long ULONG;
     typedef unsigned short USHORT;


     // **************** Part ************

     // Abstract base class of parts
     class Part
     {
     friend void showPart();

     public:
        Part():itsPartNumber(1) {}
        Part(ULONG PartNumber):itsPartNumber(PartNumber){}
        virtual ~Part(){};
        ULONG GetPartNumber() const { return itsPartNumber; }
        virtual void Display() const =0;  // must be overridden
     private:
        ULONG itsPartNumber;
     };

     // implementation of pure virtual function so that
     // derived classes can chain up
     void Part::Display() const
     {
         cout << "\nPart Number: " << itsPartNumber << endl;
     }
     // **************** Car Part ************

     class CarPart : public Part
     {
     friend void showPart();

     public:
        CarPart():itsModelYear(94){}
        CarPart(USHORT year, ULONG partNumber);
        virtual void Display() const
       {
          Part::Display(); cout << "Model Year: ";
          cout << itsModelYear << endl;
       }
     private:
        USHORT itsModelYear;
     };

     CarPart::CarPart(USHORT year, ULONG partNumber):
        itsModelYear(year),
        Part(partNumber)
     {}


     // **************** AirPlane Part ************

     class AirPlanePart : public Part
     {
     friend void showPart();

     public:
        AirPlanePart():itsEngineNumber(1){};
        AirPlanePart(USHORT EngineNumber, ULONG PartNumber);
        virtual void Display() const
       {
          Part::Display(); cout << "Engine No.: ";
          cout << itsEngineNumber << endl;
       }
     private:
        USHORT itsEngineNumber;
     };

     AirPlanePart::AirPlanePart(USHORT EngineNumber, ULONG PartNumber):
        itsEngineNumber(EngineNumber),
        Part(PartNumber)
     {}

     // **************** Part Node ************
     class PartNode
     {
     public:
         PartNode (Part*);
         ~PartNode();
         void SetNext(PartNode * node) { itsNext = node; }
         PartNode * GetNext() const;
         Part * GetPart() const;
      private:
         Part *itsPart;
         PartNode * itsNext;
      };

      // PartNode Implementations...

      PartNode::PartNode(Part* pPart):
      itsPart(pPart),
      itsNext(0)
      {}

      PartNode::~PartNode()
      {
         delete itsPart;
         itsPart = 0;
         delete itsNext;
         itsNext = 0;
      }

      // Returns NULL if no next PartNode
      PartNode * PartNode::GetNext() const
      {
            return itsNext;
      }

      Part * PartNode::GetPart() const
      {
         if (itsPart)
            return itsPart;
         else
            return NULL; //error
      }

      // **************** Part List ************
      class PartsList
      {
      public:
         PartsList();
         ~PartsList();
         // needs copy constructor and operator equals!
         Part*      Find(ULONG & position, ULONG PartNumber)  const;
         ULONG      GetCount() const { return itsCount; }
         Part*      GetFirst() const;
         static     PartsList& GetGlobalPartsList()
       {
          return  GlobalPartsList;
       }
         void       Insert(Part *);
         void       Iterate(void (Part::*f)()const) const;
         Part*      operator[](ULONG) const;
      private:
         PartNode * pHead;
         ULONG itsCount;
         static PartsList GlobalPartsList;
      };

      PartsList PartsList::GlobalPartsList;

      // Implementations for Lists...

      PartsList::PartsList():
         pHead(0),
         itsCount(0)
         {}

      PartsList::~PartsList()
      {
         delete pHead;
      }

      Part*   PartsList::GetFirst() const
      {
         if (pHead)
            return pHead->GetPart();
         else
            return NULL;  // error catch here
      }

      Part *  PartsList::operator[](ULONG offSet) const
      {
         PartNode* pNode = pHead;

         if (!pHead)
            return NULL; // error catch here

         if (offSet > itsCount)
            return NULL; // error

         for (ULONG i=0;i<offSet; i++)
            pNode = pNode->GetNext();

        return   pNode->GetPart();
      }

      Part*   PartsList::Find(ULONG & position, ULONG PartNumber)  const
      {
         PartNode * pNode = 0;
         for (pNode = pHead, position = 0;
               pNode!=NULL;
               pNode = pNode->GetNext(), position++)
         {
            if (pNode->GetPart()->GetPartNumber() == PartNumber)
               break;
         }
         if (pNode == NULL)
            return NULL;
         else
            return pNode->GetPart();
      }

      void PartsList::Iterate(void (Part::*func)()const) const
      {
         if (!pHead)
            return;
         PartNode* pNode = pHead;
         do
            (pNode->GetPart()->*func)();
         while (pNode = pNode->GetNext());
      }

      void PartsList::Insert(Part* pPart)
      {
         PartNode * pNode = new PartNode(pPart);
         PartNode * pCurrent = pHead;
         PartNode * pNext = 0;

         ULONG New =  pPart->GetPartNumber();
         ULONG Next = 0;
         itsCount++;

         if (!pHead)
         {
            pHead = pNode;
            return;
         }

         // if this one is smaller than head
         // this one is the new head
         if (pHead->GetPart()->GetPartNumber() > New)
         {
            pNode->SetNext(pHead);
            pHead = pNode;
            return;
         }

         for (;;)
         {
            // if there is no next, append this new one
            if (!pCurrent->GetNext())
            {
               pCurrent->SetNext(pNode);
               return;
            }

            // if this goes after this one and before the next
            // then insert it here, otherwise get the next
            pNext = pCurrent->GetNext();
            Next = pNext->GetPart()->GetPartNumber();
            if (Next > New)
            {
               pCurrent->SetNext(pNode);
               pNode->SetNext(pNext);
               return;
            }
            pCurrent = pNext;
         }
      }

      int main()
      {
         PartsList pl = PartsList::GetGlobalPartsList();
         Part * pPart = 0;
         ULONG PartNumber;
         USHORT value;
         ULONG choice;

         while (1)
         {
            cout << "(0)Quit (1)Car (2)Plane: ";
            cin >> choice;

            if (!choice)
               break;

            cout << "New PartNumber?: ";
            cin >>  PartNumber;

            if (choice == 1)
            {
               cout << "Model Year?: ";
               cin >> value;
               pPart = new CarPart(value,PartNumber);
            }
            else
            {
               cout << "Engine Number?: ";
               cin >> value;
               pPart = new AirPlanePart(value,PartNumber);
            }

            pl.Insert(pPart);
         }
         void (Part::*pFunc)()const = &Part::Display;
         pl.Iterate(pFunc);

         cout << "\n\n\nThere are " << pl.GetCount() << " items in the list" << endl;


        return 0;
     }
```

I tried using The Find() in the PartsList class. Does Find() take the partnumber and return the address of the part?

I wrote this to dereference the retrieved address, but it gives me the error `no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << * show'`:

```
    int findnumber;
         ULONG position;
         cout << "Enter Partnumber" << endl;
         cin >> findnumber;
         Part* show = pl.Find(position, findnumber);
         cout << *show;
```

Am i doing this all wrong? D: Show me please...

Comment: it would be better if you be more clear about your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function Find does take a part number, but returns a pointer to a part, which is not the same as the address of the part (that would be a reference, denoted by an &). In addition, Find takes a reference to a variable called 'position', so after calling the Find function, the variable that was passed in for 'position' will contain the value of where the part is in the linked list.

The reason you can't use the << operator, is that it hasn't been provided for the Part class. However, from the source code provided, it looks like the objective is for you to understand Polymorphism and rather than trying to use <<, call the Display function on the part that you have found. e.g: -

```
Part* part = pl.Find(position, findnumber);
part->Display();
```

This will display the text for the relevant type of part, so if the part returned was a CarPart, the CarPart's Display function will be called, whereas if the part is an AirPlane part, its Display function is called.

If you wanted to use the stream operator (<<) you'd need to overload the io operators, which you can read more about [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/).

Comment: Thank you very much Merlin your answer helped me alot and it worked. I will try to understand Polymorphism better. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The class `PartsList` already has a `Find()` method that could be used to retrieve any part based on its partnumber. You can then call the `Display()` method of that part.

Comment: To my understanding, Find() takes a partnumber and returns the address of that part, right? how do i assign that to a pointer and dereference it?